# Method name expected C# SQL Server visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I'm trying to read data from the data source and I got this error in the ExecuteReader method,
When I try to show the result in some label.

I'm getting the error here `idlabel.Text = myraeder("id");` under `myreader` varibale

```
private void Searchbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dataConnectin);
   con.Open();

   string searchsql = "SELECT * from Table WHERE Name=" + searchtxt.Text + "";
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(searchsql, con);

   SqlDataReader myraeder;
   myraeder = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   myraeder.Read();

   idlabel.Text = myraeder("id");
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Use this one `myraeder["id"].ToString();`

Comment: Be aware of the sql injection possibility here.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use square brackets instead of round brackets.
2. Convert the field to string.

```cs
    idlabel.Text = myraeder["id"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the data in this way:

```
idlabel.Text = myraeder["id"].ToString();
con.Close();
```

> **And** do not forget to close the connection after getting required data.

Comment: Is it worked for you and your issue is resolved ?

Answer (score 1):

There are so many errors that are obvious. Let me show you a better way to write code. Follow me!

- Give the variables proper names and casing.
- Use asynchrony.
- Use parameters in sql queries.
- Release resources by wrapping them in `using`.
- Enclose names in brackets in sql.

```
private async void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync();

        string searchSql = "SELECT * from [Table] WHERE [Name]=@name";

        using (var command = new SqlCommand(searchSql, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = searchTextBox.Text;

            using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    idLabel.Text = reader["id"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```